# What is causing my line offset problem in Github's diff?

Tags: git, github, diff

I could use some help figuring out what's wrong with diff in a repo. I made two relatively simple changes, one was simply deleting an @media rule in a .css file, easily seen here in this commit's diff: https://github.com/TryGhost/Casper/commit/b12f5206eb5c63bd7faeed8a5c38089518a38695

That looks completely fine and reasonable, each selector matches up nicely in diff.

When I fix the formatting and unindent the selectors, again, diff looks great, each line matches up with its corresponding selector nicely:

[image]

https://github.com/TryGhost/Casper/commit/73c0befea23d6299e28280cc07b78d9da99c1c29

But, when I diff the overall branch with just those two commits, this is where everything goes off the rails with diff:

[image]

https://github.com/Torqu3Wr3nch/nightCasper/compare/master...Torqu3Wr3nch:darkTheme?diff=split&expand=1

I can no longer do a nice side-by-side comparison of changes.

**Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?** I anticipate that the upstream repo this is forked from will change fairly often so I want to get things right going forward.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed the indentations in the second commit. Githubs default view doesn't like this.
Try the w=1 parameter.
E.g.
https://github.com/Torqu3Wr3nch/nightCasper/compare/master...Torqu3Wr3nch:darkTheme?diff=split&expand=1&w=1

Some further reading: 
https://github.blog/2018-05-01-ignore-white-space-in-code-review/

> When reviewing code, a diff with a number of trivial white space changes can create enough noise that it’s difficult to focus on code changes.

Comment: Thanks, Dennis. I appreciate the suggestion, but what I don't understand is why is it fine in the second commit, where I actually made the indentation changes, and perfectly lined up/easy to read there, but then goes off the rails as soon as I look at the overall branch? Is there something I am doing wrong by changing the formatting? Is there something I should be doing in VS Code so I don't run into this problem in the first place? Thanks again!

Comment: This is only speculation from me: I think Github handles indentation in some custom logic internally for the diff view. It seems like the indentation was wrong before the first commit, that's why you fixed it? I suspect there is some trimming before git uses the diff. As for "fixing" this I would say you are SOL, or in other words: you did nothing wrong

Comment: Thanks, I even tried a few other test branches, one where I did the formatting correctly the first time in one commit. That made no difference. I also tried another branch where I used .gitattributes as documented here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting. No luck. Also tried converting tabs to spaces (which wasn't the case because the remote repo also wasn't using tabs) still no luck. Starting to think that I really am out of luck. I guess I should just use your w=1 suggestion and see what the future holds?

Answer (score 0):

your editor did an autoformat, which switched tabs with spaces.

note: some tools ignore whitespaces when showing diffs.